# addListener is deprecated. What's the alternative?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, events, media-queries

I have a simple JS code to move HTML element from one div to another when the screen's width is 1200px or less. It works nicely but the addListener event handler is crossed out in VSC and I get the warning that it's deprecated. How should I change the code to avoid that warning?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1200px)");
  
  function move(x) {
      if (x.matches) {
        $('.menu').insertBefore($('.popup ul'));
      }

      else {
        $('.menu').insertAfter($('.logo'));
      }
  }

  move(x);
  x.addListener(move);
});
```

Comment: addEventListener?

Comment: Read the documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList/addListener

Comment: what isn't clear in that doc @Barmar is which event to listen for - I believe it's `"change"`

Comment: @Bravo Yes, I've just been searching for that, I found an example here: https://www.tabnine.com/code/javascript/functions/builtins/MediaQueryList/addListener and it uses `change`.

Comment: @Bravo I already tried it but then the 'else' statement doesn't work.

Comment: The argument to an event listener is an event object, not the element, so you need to use `event.target` instead of `x`.

Comment: @Barmar All I am asking is: Is there just a simple modification in my code to avoid the warning or not? I have already read the documentation and got the conclusion to avoid addListener, but I still don't understand what's the alternative in my code.

Comment: @Bravo Well yes, there is an explanation which I didn't notice before, but even with that explanation, I would never be able to modify the code myself since I am a complete beginner. If I knew better, I wouldn't even ask the question in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert to `addEventListener` with the `change` event. You'll need to extract the target from the `event` argument to pass that to `move()`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1200px)");

  function move(x) {
    if (x.matches) {
      $('.menu').insertBefore($('.popup ul'));
    } else {
      $('.menu').insertAfter($('.logo'));
    }
  }

  move(x);
  x.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    move(event.target);
  });
});
```

Comment: could you also do `x.addEventListener('change', move)` and use `if (this.matches)` .... of course, the `move(x)` would then be `move.call(x)` - guess yours is better :p

Comment: @Bravo That would work, too. But `move.call(x)` is kind of obscure.

Comment: He could also just get rid of the `x` parameter and just refer to it as a closure variable.

Comment: @Barmar I am female haha

Comment: "You'll need to extract the target from the event argument to pass that to move().", `event.target === x` With this code the best is to get rid of the `x` parameter in `function move(x) {`.

Comment: Indeed you are, sorry about that.